# How do I get graphicsmagick to draw a line inside a BMP file?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I've installed GraphicsMagick and the gm command responds inside the shell.
I have a BMP file of 400 by 400 white pixels.
I tried this

```
gm convert -draw 'line 10,10 200,200' blank_canvas.bmp
```

but all I got was

```
gm convert unable to open file (10,10)[No such file or directory]
```

I also tried

```
gm convert blank_canvas.bmp -draw 'line 10,10 200,200'
```

and got

```
gm convert: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition (line) [No such file or directory].
```

And while we are at it, how do I get it to draw a big number of lines, inputing the data from a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a white BMP:

```
gm convert -size 400x400 xc:white white.bmp
```

Draw a red line on it, being careful to specify both an input and output image:

```
gm convert white.bmp -fill red -draw 'line 10,10 200,200' result.bmp
```

If you don't want to specify an input and an output file because you want the operation done *"in-place"*, use `mogrify`:

```
gm mogrify -fill red -draw 'line 10,10 200,200' white.bmp
```

You can also use `mogrify` if you have hundreds of images to apply the drawing to, like this:

```
gm mogrify -fill red -draw 'line 10,10 200,200' *.bmp
```

Be careful - `mogrify` is a **VERY POWERFUL** command that can irreversibly alter lots of images very quickly.

---

If you want to do lots of lines, all listed in a text file, make it with a format like this and save as `draw.txt`:

```
fill red
line 10,10,200,200
fill blue
line 200,10,10,200
fill lime
line 80,120,300,400
```

And run it like this:

```
gm convert white.bmp -draw @draw.txt result.bmp
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use an `MVG` file like this:

```
viewbox 0 0 400 400
fill white rectangle 0,0 400,400
fill red line 10,10,200,200
fill blue line 200,10,10,200
fill lime line 80,120,300,400
fill magenta circle 250,250 250,400
```

And run it like this:

```
gm convert mvg:lines.mvg result.png
```

Or, like this if you have a program that generates the lines:

```
cat lines.mvg | gm convert mvg:- result.png
```

[image]

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick, draw lines, multiple lines, multiple shapes, MVG.

Comment: I guess the file draw.txt could be used for imagemagick as well, right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much the whole answer is equally applicable to ImageMagick.